# How to display progress bar until whole aspx page is load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a master page Root.master and a page default.aspx . I want to display progress bar until whole default.aspx page is loaded .

I tried following code:-

```
<html>
<head><title>xx</title>
</head>
<body style="visibility:hidden;" onload="function(){document.body.visibility='visible'}">
<img src="xxxx.gif" style="visibility:visible !important">

</body>
</html>
```

But problem is that I do not have body on default.aspx , it is on root.master , if we put it on root.master, it apply all pages which inherit from root.master .
So there is another for it .

Please suggest me usable link or samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your sample if you are using jQuery, you can use following re-factoring to your code

```
 $(document).load(function(){
     $('body').css('visibility','visible');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and then do a little code something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(){  // Wait until the page has finished loading
        if ($(".ProgressBar"))  // Detect the element with class ProgressBar
        {
          $(".ProgressBar").hide();  // If found, set it to be display:none;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ProgressBar">
      <img src="Whatever.gif" alt="Please wait..." />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also doable without jQuery but it's just so much easier to use it ;)

That way the progress bar gif loads, and once the page is done it is set to invisible.

I hope that might help!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention any libraries, so here is a pure js solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/TTU7v/

The idea is to put the script as close to the opening body tag (but after it!) as possible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.visibility = "hidden";
window.onload = function(){body.style.visibility = "visible";};
</script>
```